# ADB authorization prompt missing in Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803)

Tags: rooting, adb, sony-xperia-z3-compact

I just bought a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803) and I'm trying to root it. I'm following [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/general/how-to-root-backup-drm-keys-t3013343) for instructions, but I got stuck at the "Rooting with exploit" step as I can't authorize the connection.

I've already tried:

- Restarting the ADB server
- Rebooting the device
- Rebooting my PC
- Changing from MTP to MSC and back
- Disabling and then enabling USB debugging
- Disabling and then enabling 'Developer options'
- Using various ADB drivers
- Using different ADB binaries
- Deleting my `.Android` folder
- Deleting ADB copies in other tools' folders
- Plugging the device in another port
- Any combination of the above that I can think of

I can't find any other possible solution to this issue on Google. I'm hoping you guys will be able to enlighten me and finally be able to solve this.

**PS**: Something tells me that my PC is the problem here, as I was never able to do this with my old SGS3 either, but I ran out of ideas about what could be causing it anyway.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but you might consider seeing if your device is recognized by adb in other computer. If yes, you might proceed with reinstalling the os(windows/linux) on your PC. I once had problem with Xperia P, I had to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, before step 13 "Enable USB debugging on the phone (Settings => About phone => Click 7 times on Android Build to unlock developer options)" make sure you have enabled MTP over USB on the phone. Sometimes it helps to revoke the approved debug devices as well.